# SQL what index to add to query on a join table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have tables that when joined together will be queried by just 1 geographical state (e.g. NY, TX) and possibly a county - there's a state and county column.

Checklist table

```
id (pk) | name | state | county | type
```

Checklist Item table

```
id (pk) | checklist_id fk checklist(id) | name | description
```

Should I add indexes on state and county columns to efficiently query for checklist items by geographical location (state and/or county)? County column may be null for many states, but for states with counties, there may be many counties.

In the checklist items table, there would be a lot more of rows as it would hold info about every possible item in a checklist.

Would I need to add an index for checklist_id (a foreign key) in checklist item table, as well? Or is it automatically indexed since its the primary key of checklist table?

Majority of my queries would be on the joined table of the two tables.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? "_Or is it automatically indexed since its the primary key of checklist table_" will have different answers.

Comment: Depends whether you filter on the state or county, or whether you just want everything. Basic rule of thumb is: `WHERE =` columns first in the index key, then join `ON` columns, then `WHERE >, <>, <,` columns, then `ORDER BY` columns` If your DBMS supports it, also add `INCLUDE` columns for any other columns referenced.

Comment: oh, gotcha - i'm using postgres

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your typical query is something like this:

```
select . . . 
from checklist cl join
     checklistitem cli
     on cli.checklist_id = cl.id
where cl.state = ?;
```

For this type of query, you want indexes on:

- `checklist(state, id)`
- `checklistitem(checklist_id)`

If you also want `county` to be included and it is normally selected with a state, as in:

```
select . . . 
from checklist cl join
     checklistitem cli
     on cli.checklist_id = cl.id
where cl.state = ? and cl.county = ?;
```

Then the indexes you want are:

- `checklist(state, county, id)`
- `checklistitem(checklist_id)`

These indexes will work on both tables.

Notes:

- In some databases, the primary key is automatically added to an index.  Even so, I'm usually explicitly about including it.
- In some databases, foreign key declarations automatically create an index.  But that depends on the database.

Comment: What about `INCLUDE`s??

Comment: What is the point of including `id` in the index on `checklist`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . This allows the index to be used for the `join` conditions, if all the rows are visible.  Note that the Postgres tag was added after I answered.

Comment: But on each conceivable database that will be a nested loop join with `checklist` on the outer side, right? I cannot see how adding `id` to the index would help in that case. Or were you envisioning a merge join?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . No.  Just a delay or avoidance of looking up the data pages.  Most databases update the index when the data is updated, so there is equivalent to "visibility".

Comment: Well, that won't help with PostgreSQL, unless `id` and `state` are the only columns from `checklist` in the `SELECT` list.